# styles.css - Error: (0 , _identifier.getUndoPath) is not a function

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I am trying to setup an Angular app using Nx CLI. I have used the command

`npx create-nx-workspace --preset=angular`

A workspace gets created. When I run that using

`npx nx serve --port 4300`

I end up getting an error in my cmd

`styles.css - Error: (0 , _identifier.getUndoPath) is not a function`

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue and why is this happening? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue, I tried using the NX console extension for vscode but no luck, the other projects like `nest` serve just fine, but angular doesn't even build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a temporary bug, there is an issue about this in Github, the developers are aware of this and are trying to fix it. You might want to check it for some quick hotfixes.
[Github Issue Here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/6612)

**Here is what a collaborator suggests**

- Delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`
- Install again using `npm install`

Comment: This suggestion works, I had the same problem (not using nx, but a pure angular workspace), after updating angular to  12.2.0. Thanks !

Comment: Does not work for me. Downgrading @angular-devkit/build-angular to ~2.1.0 did work, see issue linked above.

Comment: I had this issue in my NX project and this fixed it.
Angular 12, Node 14.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/6612). In the meantime, downgrade `build-angular` by running:

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@~12.1.0 --save-dev
```